# How to solve "PG::CannotCoerce: ERROR: cannot cast type bigint to timestamp with time zone" error in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, group-by, ruby-on-rails-5

i want to show my sales index that group by month, i already try to use filter or groupdate gem, but i got this error

> PG::CannotCoerce: ERROR:  cannot cast type bigint to timestamp with
>   time zone LINE 1: ... NULL) GROUP BY (DATE_TRUNC('month',
>   ("sales"."id"::timestam...
>                                                                ^ : SELECT "sales".* FROM "sales" WHERE ("sales"."id" IS NOT NULL) GROUP
>   BY (DATE_TRUNC('month', ("sales"."id"::timestamptz) AT TIME ZONE
>   'Asia/Bangkok')) AT TIME ZONE 'Asia/Bangkok'

i also try to remove the time_zone, but i got error like this

> "invalid argument to TimeZone[]: :created_at"

```
class SalesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_sale, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /sales
  # GET /sales.json
  def index
    @sales = Sale.group_by_month(:id, :created_at,format: "%B %Y", time_zone: "Hanoi")
  end
```

i expect the index was group by month, that extract from created_at with timestamp type column, like

```
January
1, description, total, commission, created_at 
2, description, total, commission, created_at 

February
3, description, total, commission, created_at 

March
4, description, total, commission, created_at
```

error : https://i.stack.imgur.com/3dxae.png

source code: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7AJnY.png

Answer (score 1):

First of all looks like there is a mistake in this line:

```
@sales = Sale.group_by_month(:id, :created_at,format: "%B %Y", time_zone: "Hanoi")
```

Look at the example for [groupdate gem](https://github.com/ankane/groupdate):

```
User.group_by_week(:created_at, time_zone: "Pacific Time (US & Canada)")
```

First argument (`id`) is excessive and your code should look like:

```
@sales = Sale.group_by_month(:created_at, format: "%B %Y", time_zone: "Hanoi")
```

That's why, actually, you receive the error message "PG::CannotCoerce: ERROR: cannot cast type bigint to timestamp with time zone...". `"sales"."id"::timestamptz` in generated SQL query means converting `id` column (integer) to timestamp (timestamptz).

I hope it will be helpful.